# Configuring Chrome Remote Desktop in Debian 9.11

Tags: debian, gnome, chrome, remote-desktop

After installing the Chrome extension and associated .deb package for Chrome Remote Desktop, I've had trouble configuring it correctly.  [Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en-GB) only cover installation under Ubuntu, so I've been trying to translate them into their Debian equivalents.

The instructions say to create a file `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` containing the command needed to launch your desktop session, which can be copied from your "*.desktop" file in `/usr/share/xsessions/`.

For me, this command is `gnome-classic-session`.
According to their instructions, my `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` file should contain:

```bsh
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-classic-session"
```

However, my system doesn't even have `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session`

I've tried the following two combinations without any luck:

```bsh
exec /usr/sbin/gdm3 gnome-session-classic

exec "/usr/bin/gnome-classic-session --session=gnome-classic-session"
```

Clearly I'm no Debian/Gnome expert, so I'd be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was overthinking this one.  Everything works fine after deleting the `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` file I had created, so it is not necessary.